Drop shadow is missing on SWT Shell if redraw set to false
I'm trying to create a shell that contains a SWT Browser. The final shell size is being calculated based on the browser content, so to prevent the size of the shell jumping around I'm setting redraw of the shell to false and only reactivate it in the ProgressListener of the browser. If I do it like that the usual drop shadow the shell has is missing after the redraw. I'm on Windows 10.
final Shell shell = new Shell(parentShell, SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.TOOL | SWT.NO_FOCUS);
shell.setRedraw(false);

final Browser browser = new Browser(shell , SWT.NONE);  
browser.setText("Example html text");                                                                                                                     
browser.addProgressListener(ProgressListener.completedAdapter(progressCompleted -> {
    Point size = calculateBrowserSize();
    shell.setSize(size.x, size.y);
    browser.setSize(size.x, size.y);
    shell.setRedraw(true);
}));

shell.open();

EDIT: Non-optimal solution I found, use setSize instead of setRedraw. So it still shows a shell with the wrong size for a split second, but it is virtually invisible.
final Shell shell = new Shell(parentShell, SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.TOOL | SWT.NO_FOCUS);
shell.setSize(1, 1); // (0,0) doesn't work, also produces shell without drop shadow

final Browser browser = new Browser(shell , SWT.NONE);  
browser.setText("Example html text");                                                                                                                     
browser.addProgressListener(ProgressListener.completedAdapter(progressCompleted -> {
    Point size = calculateBrowserSize();
    shell.setSize(size.x, size.y);
    browser.setSize(size.x, size.y);
}));

shell.open();


Are you sure it is not the SWT.TOOL style that is not drawing the drop shadow, that often changes how the window looks. (I don't run Windows so can't test this)

No, removing it does not make a difference. Also when I remove the setRedraw method calls it draws with the drop shadow.

You could try calling shell.setVisible(false) at the start then make it visible at the end.

Sadly this doesn't work either since shell.setVisible(true) is called inside shell.open(). So it leads to a visible wrong sized shell opening and then changing to correct size.
